# Passing MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass() vs passing Class<?> to getLogger method

Tags: java

I recently came across a logger declared as below:

```
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass());
```

Is there an advantage to declaring the logger in this manner as opposed to declaring it 'normally' like this:

```
`private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class`);
```

Comment: with the second code, everyone will know what is happening. the first will probably cause some head scratches as to what logging has to do with MethodHandles.

Comment: @Clashsoft I think it'll be alright if you see the same thing all over the codebase.

Comment: From the performance, perspective is really doesn't matter much. The first one is something not followed mostly and makes few devs wonder what's happening. The second one is most of the dev comfortable with and more readable.

Comment: @Clashsoft yeah that's why I'm here :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using `MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass()` avoids embedding the class name, which will often be wrong when the line is copyed and pasted.