# MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass() vs getClass()

Tags: java

Can anyone tell me the (subtle) differences of

**version 1:**

```
protected final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(getClass());
```

vs

**version 2:**

```
protected final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass());
```

Is **version 2** in general faster than **version 1**?

I guess  *version 1* uses reflection (on runtime) to determine the current class while *version 2* does not need to use reflection, or (is the check done on build time)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are *entirely* different things. The documentation of `lookupClass`, specifically says:

> Tells which class is performing the lookup. It is this class against which checks are performed for visibility and access permissions

So it's the class which *performs* the lookup. It's not necessarily the class where you call `MethodHandles.lookup()`. What I mean by that is that this:

```
Class<?> c = MethodHandles.privateLookupIn(String.class, MethodHandles.lookup()).lookupClass();
System.out.println(c);
```

will print `String.class` and not the class where you define this code.

The only "advantage" (besides confusing every reader of this code), is that if you copy/paste that log creation line across various source files, it will use the proper class, if you, by accident, don't edit it (which probably happens).

Also notice that:

```
protected final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(getClass());
```

should be a `static` field, usually, and you can't call `getClass` if it is.

A `JMH` test shows that there is no performance gain to obfuscate your code that much:

```java
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
@Warmup(iterations = 5, time = 2, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
@Measurement(iterations = 5, time = 2, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
public class LookupTest {

    private static final MethodHandles.Lookup LOOKUP = MethodHandles.lookup();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws RunnerException {
        Options opt = new OptionsBuilder().include(LookupTest.class.getSimpleName())
                .verbosity(VerboseMode.EXTRA)
                .build();
        new Runner(opt).run();
    }
    
    @Benchmark
    @Fork(3)
    public Class<?> getClassCall() {
        return getClass();
    }
    
    @Benchmark
    @Fork(3)
    public Class<?> methodHandlesInPlaceCall() {
        return MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass();
    }
    
    @Benchmark
    @Fork(3)
    public Class<?> methodHandlesCall() {
        return LOOKUP.lookupClass();
    }
}
```

results:

```
Benchmark                            Mode  Cnt  Score   Error  Units
LookupTest.getClassCall              avgt   15  2.264 ± 0.044  ns/op
LookupTest.methodHandlesCall         avgt   15  2.262 ± 0.030  ns/op
LookupTest.methodHandlesInPlaceCall  avgt   15  4.890 ± 0.783  ns/op
```

Comment: Eugene: thanks for the very good eplanation :) By the way, `should be a static field, usually, and you can't call getClass if it is`, In my case, the logger is defined within an abstract class so I need the non-static version.

Comment: @nimo23 I see, we use lombok for that via `@Slf4j`

Answer (score 5):

There is no reflection involved in you first case. [Object#getClass()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass()) is mapped to JVM's native method.

Your [second case](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.Lookup.html#lookupClass--) is **not** drop-in replacement for `Object#getClass()`, it is used to lookup method handles.

So subtle difference is, they are used for completely different purposes.

Comment: Ok, If found out that using MethodHandles within Interface does not give me the runtime class but the interface class. So it's not a drop-in replacement. Don't know the reason why some prefer MethodHandles instead of getClass() when defining a logger.

Comment: It's definitely not common to use `MethodHandles` to define logger. Do you have any reference to such code?

Comment: For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65117135/passing-methodhandles-lookup-lookupclass-vs-passing-class-to-getlogger-me or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936684/getting-the-class-name-from-a-static-method-in-java. But they don't explain why I should prefer one over the other (for example, in terms of performance, lookup costs, ..). Maybe you can explain it better:)

Comment: @nimo23 performance wise, there is almost no diff.